# How to convert milliseconds to timestamp in kotlin programming

Tags: kotlin, timestamp

how to convert milliseconds to timestamp in kotlin.

time in milliseconds : 1575959745000 **to format:** dd/MM/yyyy HH:MM:ss

Comment: Which platform are you targeting with your Kotlin code? If JVM, then you can simply use all the `java.time` facilities from Kotlin.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

EDIT: now, there is the [kotlinx-datetime](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx-datetime) library

---

There is no pure Kotlin support for dates at the moment, only durations.
You will have to rely on the target platform's facilities for date/time parsing and formatting.

Note that, whatever platform you're targeting, it doesn't really make sense to convert a millisecond epoch to a formatted date without defining the timezone.

**If you're targeting the JVM**, then you can use the `java.time` API this way:

```kotlin
// define once somewhere in order to reuse it
val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

// JVM representation of a millisecond epoch absolute instant
val instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(1575959745000L)

// Adding the timezone information to be able to format it (change accordingly)
val date = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(instant, ZoneId.systemDefault())
println(formatter.format(date)) // 10/12/2019 06:35:45
```

**If you're targeting JavaScript**, things get trickier. You can do the following to use some sort of default time zone, and some close-enough format (defined by the locale `"en-gb"`):

```
val date = Date(1575959745000)
println(date.toLocaleString("en-gb")) // 10/12/2019, 07:35:45
```

You have ways to specify the timezone according the standard JS API for [`Date.toLocaleString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString). But I haven't dug much into the details.

**As for native**, I have no idea.

Comment: **Joffrey** Thanks for prompt support.

Comment: ```jave.time``` API supported since Android API 26, some developers (including me!) still support apps since Android API 21

Comment: @Gleichmut be grateful that he extended it to api 26. nobody uses 21.

Comment: @Ino, Android 5.0 and 5.1 (API 21) altogether is just 1% of market share, but keeping in mind total amount of **active** Android devices it is **30 000 000** devices which is still  valuable market. The most important thing is your target audience and their requirements, in my TA I have demand to support Android 5.